# Node JS. Jade/Pug page is not rendered

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, pug

I'm trying to refresh table with SQL data by click the tab button but it doesn't work.

In app.js:

```
app.post('/updateTable', function(req, res) {
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('users.db');

  db.serialize(function() {
    db.all("SELECT * FROM user_info", function(err, rows) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Student Registration', rows: rows });
    });
  });

  db.close();
});
```

In index.pug:

```
#tabs-2.box
  table
    thead
      tr#tabTit
        th Name
        th Birthday
        th EduID
        th EduGroup
        th Phone
        th Email
    tbody
      - for (var item in rows)
          tr
            td= rows[item].name
            td= rows[item].date
            td= rows[item].eduID
            td= rows[item].gr
            td= rows[item].phone
            td= rows[item].email
```

In clien-side JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#tabs, #tabs-2').tabs({
      activate: function(event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/updateTable'
                });
      }
    });
});
```

The post-request is succefully handled but "res.render" does not work.

Where am I screwing up?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! It works with success-handler in the ajax-request. There is dynamically refresh table now.

Render pug-page 'table'

```
db.all("SELECT * FROM user_info", function(err, rows) {
    res.render('table', { rows: rows });
});
```

Success-handler

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/updateTable',
    success: function(data) {
               $('#tabs-2').html(data);
             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the post request is handled? You are declaring the `activate` function, but never calling it.

If that's not the issue, try returning the res.render. It becomes:

`return res.render('index', { title: 'Student Registration', rows: rows });`

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have that message in console when click the tab: POST /updateTable 200 79.484 ms - 1903. And putting return before res.render did not help anyway.

Comment: What happens if you ```console.log(rows)``` the line above your res.render?

Comment: You can also add ```if (err) console.log(err)``` the first line below your db.all query (first line in the callback)

Comment: For example 'console.log(rows[1].name)' works but res.render line seems to ignore completelly without any errors.